# Saving path during tree recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm stuck with a bit of an annoying problem: I have a tree and want to traverse it recursively. During the recursion I would like to save the current path since in the nodes only the current value is saved. I use following code for it:

```
def getPaths(tree, level, path):
    copyPath = list(path)
    if level > 1:
        if not tree.children:
           '''do some non important stuff'''
    for child in tree.children:
        copyPath.append(child.data.value)
        getPaths(child,level+1, copyPath)
```

First I tried to simply do it without copying the list, but this obviously couldn't work. But even when I copy the list, it seems only to use one global list to collect all the values instead of collecting them pathwise into different list.

I would appreciate some help to this (probably) easy problem.

Comment: It's definitely going to keep passing the same list for performance reasons (you wouldn't like the other way!) but you can just use a different data structure, or the same one differently. If you want to, just keep a list of lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in an immutable style, look towards `itertools` and the `chain` method:

```
for child in tree.children:
   getPaths(child, level+1, chain(path, [child.data.value]))
```

Now you've got an `iterator` that you can iterate over which is dependent not on copying a list but rather something that represents the initial "path" plus a new "node."

**Edit**:

Just remember that you are dealing with an `iterator` so that if you want to be able to iterate over it AND then pass that to another function, you might want to `tee` it (also from itertools.)